# No MySQL Server 8.0.16 included in the installer

Tags: mysql-8.0

I downloaded the MySQL community Edition 8.0.16 in my windows 7 32-bit. However there was

Comment: This is not a complete question

Answer (score 1):

[EOL notices](https://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html) June 23, 2016
Support EOL for Windows 7:

Per the MySQL Support Lifecycle policy regarding ending support for OS versions that are obsolete or have reached end of life, we plan to discontinue building all MySQL binaries for Microsoft Windows 7 as of June 23, 2016

[Supported Platforms](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html) Microsoft Windows 10  x86_64